# State a correlation that associates a distinct natural number with each string made from the infinite alphabet set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, order-theory

We are asked to take strings made from the set of infinite alphabet letters and assign them each one unique natural number. So from a string, we would get a unique number. We also have to make sure that if given a number, we can find it's unique string. So there is a 1-1 correspondence between the strings and the numbers. The question shows one way of doing things which is wrong because a number can end up being equal to two different strings since we are working with an infinite alphabet set. But this is the only way I can think go assigning strings to numbers. I cannot figure out how I would assign strings to numbers so that each number would also get a unique string. Any help would be appreciated and a final answer would help me a lot. Thank you.

[Here is the complete problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kn8FL.png)

Answer (score 1):

Let $p_{1},p_{2},\ldots$ denote the prime numbers. Let $a_{i_{1}}a_{i_{2}}\cdots a_{i_{n}}$ be a string. Following the hint, 
$$
a_{i_{1}}a_{i_{2}}\cdots a_{i_{n}}\leftrightarrow p_{1}^{i_{1}}p_{2}^{i_{2}}\cdots p_{n}^{i_{n}}.
$$
In this way, the power of the $k$-th prime tells us the value of the $k$-th string. No two distinct strings get mapped to the same integer due to the [fundamental theorem of arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic).

Comment: So does this mean for the string a<sub>i1</sub>, the associated number is P<sub>1</sub> to the power of i<sub>1</sub>? For example, a<sub>1</sub> would have the associated number 2^1?

Comment: That's correct.